# How do I change height if I have content in a website within a visible viewport, no scrollbar in body?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

html code

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div class="bg">
      <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="dev-image">
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-project-image@3x.webp"
              alt="Profile Picture"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="dev-name">Ronak Radadiya</div>
          <div class="dev-profession">Lorem Ipsum</div>
          <div class="dev-content">
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi sed cumque voluptatem repudiandae illo dolor nihil, ducimus eaque voluptatibus ex perspiciatis deleniti corrupti repellendus reiciendis rem expedita laudantium, velit dicta?
            <20></20>
          </div>
          <div class="reach">
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-line@3x.webp"
              alt="Reach out"
            />
            <p>Reach Out to me</p>
            <img
              src="img/ronak-dev-ux-ui-design-line@3x.webp"
              alt="Reach out"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="social-icons">
            <a
              href="#"
              target="_blank"
            >
              <img
                src="img/ronak-whatsapp-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="whatsapp"
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://github.com/ronakradadiya" target="_blank">
              <img
                src="img/ronak-github-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="github"
              />
            </a>

            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ronak-radadiya-506861167"
              target="_blank"
            >
              <img
                src="img/ronak-linkedin-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="Linkedin"
              />
            </a>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/ronakradadiya98" target="_blank">
              <img
                src="img/ronak-twitter-product-ui-ux-design@3x.webp"
                alt="twitter"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<footer>... </footer>
```

css code

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Navbar */

.actives {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

.active {
  color: #ff4060 !important;
}

nav.bg-dark {
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color) !important;
  height: 53px !important;
}

nav.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

nav .nav-color {
  color: var(--main-text-color) !important;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-family: ProximaNovaA;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  margin: 0rem 0.6rem;
}

/* Introduction */

.bg {
  height: calc(100% - 117px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--main-bg2-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixedHeight {
  height: 507px;
}

.autoHeightBody {
  height: auto;
}

.autoHeightBg {
  height: auto;
}

.outer-box {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg1-color);
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dev-image {
  max-width: 96px;
  max-height: 96px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.dev-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dev-name {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.dev-profession {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.58px;
  color: #ff4060;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.dev-content {
  max-width: 545px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.reach {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.reach img {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.reach img:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.reach p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 41px;
}

.social-icons img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.social-icons img:nth-child(1),
.social-icons img:nth-child(2),
.social-icons img:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-adjust {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-left-content p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.footer-right-content {
  display: flex;
}

.footer-right-content div a {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.35px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
.footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bg {
    height: calc(100% - 161px);
  }

  .outer-box {
    min-height: 507px;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 575px) {
  .bg {
    height: calc(100% - 161px);
  }

  .outer-box {
    min-height: 507px;
  }

  .reach img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 108px !important;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }

  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(1) a,
  .footer-right-content div:nth-child(2) a {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  .footer,
  .footer-adjust {
    display: block !important;
  }

  .footer-left-content p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }

  .footer-right-content {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

js code

```
let styleBgBox = parseInt($(".bg").css("height"));
let styleOuterBox = parseInt($(".outer-box").css("height"));

if ($(window).outerWidth() >= 768) {
  $(".outer-box").addClass("fixedHeight");
} else {
  $(".outer-box").removeClass("fixedHeight");
}

if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox == 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else if (styleBgBox > 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
  $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
} else {
  $("body").removeClass("autoHeightBody");
  $(".bg").removeClass("autoHeightBg");
}

$(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(window).outerWidth() >= 768) {
    $(".outer-box").addClass("fixedHeight");
  } else {
    $(".outer-box").removeClass("fixedHeight");
  }

  styleBgBox = parseInt($(".bg").css("height"));
  styleOuterBox = parseInt($(".outer-box").css("height"));
  if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox == 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else if (styleBgBox > 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else if (styleBgBox < 547 && styleOuterBox > 507) {
    $("body").addClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").addClass("autoHeightBg");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("autoHeightBody");
    $(".bg").removeClass("autoHeightBg");
  }
});
```

I want to change the body height to auto if the webpage is viewed in devices which has less height so content does not overlap. But I am not able to do it in proper way. What I have done is used media queries on height which is not working.
Here is the link of what I have done till now
https://pfs-dev.netlify.app/

Comment: If you have real code that has the problem you're talking about, please remember that SO policy requires you to [put that code in your post](/help/how-to-ask), even if you add a link to the "running" version somewhere else. And on a code note, `min-height: 0px` is a noop, you don't need to add that, it's a given.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have added all the important code.

Answer (score 0):

on window resize event you can calculate real time height and set html body height accordingly

```
javascript: on window resize -> height = window.outerHeight

css: calc(100vh - [any value you want])
```

Comment: At certain height, I have to override the height to auto so that vertical scrollbar appears, but when I use vh height and override height to auto, it does not work so I have to use %

Comment: @ronakpatel,  so based on window height you can set css property to %, vh OR auto. this is the most dynamic thing you could do.

Comment: When I set the css property height to auto, in mobile device a white margin appears at the bottom

Comment: Is there any way to remove that?

Comment: I did Open your site on 1 Plus and I don't find any white margin.
All you have to do is use proper media queries.

Comment: https://portfolios-ronak.netlify.com/dev.html Please visit this website

Comment: I had edited the code after you gave some suggestion. Please have a look at it.